# Clicking AutomationElement Dialogue Box

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ui-automation

I'm automating an installer as it doesn't have a (functional) /silent switch. It works mostly fine except I've come up against what appears to be a road block - a dreaded dialogue box. 
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czPcQ.png).

What I've tried:

```
SendKey.Send/Wait(Enter/Escape)
PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK__RETURN, 0);
```

Key injection into the process

```
injector.SimulateTap((int) centre.X + 150, (int) centre.Y + 75);
```

Touch injection, does not register on this specific window, but all other windows works fine.

```
Walking over the element as if it were just a normal element
```

I'm pretty much at a loss because I'd would very much like to have to *not* press this button by hand (which also messes up the rest of the automatic install).

I know why it's not found (or I think so); because it's a new dialogue, I think enter doesn't work because its sending into the wrong process (the parent process of the dialogue box, the installer) and the touch injection I'm clueless about.

The documentation doesn't talk about how to deal with a dialogue box (it's also all C++).

Normally, I'm walking through the elements to find the next control to continue the installation. There are several controls:

```
    string[] EGalaxTouchInstallSequence = {
        @"Next >",
        "I accept the terms of the license agreement",
        @"Next >",
        "None",
        null, //this is supposed to represent a dialogue popup
        "OK",
        "Support Multi-Monitor System",
        @"Next >",
        @"Next >",
        @"Next >",
        @"Next >",
        @"Next >"
    };
```

Initially, I get all the handles from the window like so:

```
    AutomationElement UIElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(SetupWindow);
```

I iterate over the list:

```
        foreach (string button in EGalaxTouchInstallSequence)
        {
            if (!FindAndClickElement(UIElement, button))
                goto error;
        }
```

`FindAndClickElement`:

```
    private bool FindAndClickElement(AutomationElement UIElement, string ElementName)
    {
        AutomationElement element = null;

        Condition ControlProperty = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ElementName);

        AutomationElementCollection elements = UIElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, ControlProperty);

        foreach (AutomationElement e in elements)
        {
            if (e.Current.Name.Contains(ElementName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match with: " + ElementName);
                element = e;
            }

        }
        //Click code is further down, irrelevant at this stage
     }
```

`Element Exists`:

```
private bool ElementExists(AutomationElement UIElement, string ElementName)
{
    Condition ControlProperty = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ElementName);

    AutomationElementCollection elements = UIElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, ControlProperty);

    foreach (AutomationElement e in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"element name: {e.Current.Name}");
        if (e.Current.Name.Contains(ElementName))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is the dialog box a child of the desktop or a child of the desktop? I have found that when I look for windows by class name I will some times find tooltips because they are windows.

Comment: It appears to be a child of the InstallShield installer - I inspected the child process of the setup process, but it has no name or anything so it's difficult to assume whether that child process is just is the inner window of the InstallShield installer or if its the dialogue box but I'm not sure how to find out as it doesnt have any other children.

Comment: So in our WPF application I do something like this to prevent myself from finding tool tips. `FindAll("...").FirstOrDefault(a => a.FirstChild().ClassName != "ToolTip");` this is pretty slow but best solution I have found.

Comment: I can try that but the window requires me to get past the dialogue, regardless of how I do it (enter, touch, escape, etc). I'll see if I can try to find a tooltip (I don't think its a tooltip but theres no other controls that are close).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check to see what is there right before you go to get the element. I use a method like this to get everything.

```
  /// <summary>
  ///    Returns all children elements of an automation element.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="automationElement"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static List<AutomationElement> AllChildren(AutomationElement automationElement)
  {
     if (automationElement == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(automationElement));

     AutomationElement firstChild = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(automationElement);
     if (firstChild == null)
        return new List<AutomationElement>();

     List<AutomationElement> children = new List<AutomationElement> { firstChild };

     AutomationElement sibling;
     int childIndex = 0;
     while ((sibling = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetNextSibling(children[childIndex])) != null)
     {
        children.Add(sibling);
        childIndex++;
     }

     return children;
  }
```

Also as I put in my comment make sure you are not accidentally finding a tooltip by using something like this `FindAll("...").FirstOrDefault(a => a.FirstChild().ClassName != "ToolTip");`. The tool tip will generally not show up because of how quickly the application is clicking things so it will have a (-1, -1) for its position.

Comment: This seems interesting. Which element would I apply this to? The main window? I'll apply this to every "Next >" button to see what it spits out, thank you.

Comment: I would try the main window since generally modal dialog are owned by the window that spawned them but this is dependent on the developer claiming ownership of them. Our application has some dialog the desktop owns (because we did not claim ownership of them) and some our application does.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try, you might not get a response until monday though :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to have any children. I ran a foreach on the result of your function on: `AutomationElement UIElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(SetupWindow);` and when `FindAndClick` is called.

Comment: Another thing I would suggest is retrying finding the element you are looking for. I created a library specifically for this purpose https://github.com/maxinfet/Mulligan. It encapsulated the retry logic from FlaUI and TestStack.White.

Comment: @memhave Here is the how FlaUI retries https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.Core/Tools/Retry.cs

Comment: @Memhave and here is how TestStack.White retries https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/Utility/Retry.cs

Comment: I'll give those a look but it's not the end of the world if we have to install it manually.